# jpa criteria builder writing simple query

Tags: java, jsf, jpa

I want to select from database entities with certain price and with certain type but the  result list is empty using criteria builder.I came to this code

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
Root<Advert> from = criteriaQuery.from(Advert.class);
Predicate predicate1 = criteriaBuilder.ge(from.get("price"), x1);
Predicate predicate2 = criteriaBuilder.le(from.get("price"), x2);
Predicate predicate4 = criteriaBuilder.like(from.get("type"), type);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicate1, predicate2, predicate4));
TypedQuery<Object> typedQuery = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Object> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

But the it returns empty List.How to rewrite it correctly?

Comment: Enable SQL tracing, thus you could see generated SQL queries in order to find out what went wrong with query builder.

Comment: Try to add: `criteriaQuery.select(from);`